# WindowManager with Animation (is it possible?)

Tags: java, android, animation, view, window-managers

Is there any way to inflate a view with WindowManager using Animation (at android's project)? I just can't do it even using the examples in sites! I used many examples but none worked!

```
public BannerLayout(Activity activity, final Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 

    wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);    

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    this.popupLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_activity, null);
    this.popupLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
    this.setActive(false);

    wm.addView(this.popupLayout, params);

    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


private void show(){
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    this.popupLayout.setAnimation(in);

    this.setActive(true);
    this.popupLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm not sure about exact requirements for Your task, but there's two ways to provide animation to window:

1. Use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.windowAnimations` like the following:

   ```
   params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Translucent;
   ```
2. Add additonal 'container' view, because `WindowManager` is not a real `ViewGroup` and so normal animation for adding views is not working with it. [This question has been asked already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537672/animate-system-alert-type-view), however it lacks the code. I would apply it the following way:

   ```
   public class BannerLayout extends View {

       private final Context mContext;

       private final ViewGroup mPopupLayout;

       private final ViewGroup mParentView;

       public BannerLayout(Activity activity, final Context context) {
           super(context);

           mContext = context;

           final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                   PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

           final WindowManager mWinManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           mPopupLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_activity, null);
           mPopupLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

           params.width = ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
           params.height = ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

           // Default variant
           // params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Translucent;

           mParentView = new FrameLayout(mContext);

           mWinManager.addView(mParentView, params);

           mParentView.addView(mPopupLayout);
           mPopupLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
       }

       /**
        * Shows view
        */
       public void show(){
           final Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in);

           in.setDuration(2000);

           mPopupLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
           mPopupLayout.startAnimation(in);
       }

       /**
        * Hides view
        */
       public void hide() {
           mPopupLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to add something when you want to add an animation to `WindowManager` via : params.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Translucent; the animation style must be a system resource, it can not be an application: *A style resource defining the animations to use for this window. This must be a system resource; it can not be an application resource because the window manager does not have access to applications.*
[Android Developers DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#windowAnimations)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is indeed possible. As long as the view you want to animate is inside a container, by container I mean for instance a LinearLayout or any other layout will do. Conclusively the view to be animated should not be the root view of a window and so you should be able to animate the view `:)` Hope it helps