# Android: Thread to Update View Inside Window

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas

I have a `Service` that can draw a `Canvas` on top of all applications using a `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` which contains a custom `View`.

I am attempting to animate the `Canvas` object using a `Thread` which calls `Canvas.draw(...)` and `postInvalidate()` - I was hoping this would "move" the shape across the screen. It does not work.

I tried putting my custom `View` inside a `ViewGroup` container and added this to the `WindowManager` object - based on the following posts:

[Animate system alert type view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537672/animate-system-alert-type-view)

[WindowManager with Animation (is it possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745282/windowmanager-with-animation-is-it-possible?lq=1)

**The Canvas object position does not change - what am I doing wrong?**

Here is my code...

**CursorService.java**

```
    public class CursorService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ViewGroup cursorContainer;
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

       go();
    }

    public void go(){

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        cursor = new Cursor(this);
        cursorContainer = new LinearLayout(this);
        cursorContainer.addView(cursor);
        windowManager.addView(cursorContainer, params);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    cursor.x+=1;
                    cursor.y+=1;
                    cursor.radius=100;
               }
        }).start();
    }


    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (cursorContainer!=null) windowManager.removeView(cursorContainer);
    }
}
```

**Cursor.java**

```
public class Cursor extends View {

    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float radius;
    public Paint paint;

    public Cursor(Context context) {
        super(context);

        x=0;
        y=0;
        radius=0;
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        postInvalidate();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace suggests you are calling `invalidate`, but the code you posted is calling `postInvalidate`.  You must call `postInvalidate` to invalidate the view from a different thread.

Comment: I edited the post - turns out there aren't any errors after all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need smth like `while(true){}` cycle in your runnable because in your code `postInvalidate()` method would be called just once.

But would be much better to call `invalidate()` method in `onDraw` and calculate your circle position by using the current time.

```
public class Cursor extends View {    
    public Cursor(Context context) {
        super(context);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMills();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        long delta = System.currentTimeMills() - startTime;
        // ... calculate x and y using delta
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I used a `while(true){}` cycle in my runnable and it works!                     How would I calculate x and y using delta time?

Comment: @calcha3991 for example, you want your circle to move by 100dp by X axis in one second. So there is circle speed 0.1dp in one millisecond. So position x in any time moment will be x = startPosition + delta * speed; if you want circle to stop in some point you could check if (x > maxPosition) x = maxPosition; and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are changing `x`, `y` and `radius` from a separate thread, you should be make them volatile.  Otherwise, the changes you make to those variables (from the background thread) will not be seen by your view (on the UI thread).

```
public volatile float x;
public volatile float y;
public volatile float radius;
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any difference I'm afraid - I don't appear to be getting a `NullPointerException`

Comment: there is no race condition between threads so volatile really do nothing here